# How to work library gmailbackground withAttachments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gmail

I want to email all the jpg format photos in a folder

```
BackgroundMail.newBuilder(this)
                .withUsername("mail")
                .withPassword("password")
                .withSenderName("backup")
                .withMailTo("")
                .withMailCc("")
                .withMailBcc("")
                .withType(BackgroundMail.TYPE_PLAIN)
                .withSubject("backup")
                .withBody(ll)
                .withAttachments()
```

How to use `.withAttachments()` method?

Lib `implemention 'com.github.luongvo:GmailBackground:2.1.1'`

Please help me send all image.jpg folder /storage/sdcard0/backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all get all your jpg files into an `ArrayList` called `images`, I suggest to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get to the SD Card

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/backup");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
        images.add(listOfFiles[i].getPath());
    }
}
```

put this `ArrayList` as parameter in your method `.withAttachments(images)`

and don't forget to set READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifiest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: error code : `(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));` and `length` and `!images` and `jpg` and `remove` please help me thanks.

Comment: oops sorry, I made some mistakes.. I edited the answer , try again

Comment: Sorry, the app crashes. Logcat: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)`

Comment: this problem because `folder` is returning null, may be because the directory in the path doesn't exist (may be the path is wrong or the SD Card is not inserted), so to get the path of SD card, I suggest to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` .. I edited the answer again with this method, try it

Comment: Sorry i tried on emulator it was ok but on real device gave the following error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array` **Excuse me for taking your time**

Comment: any ways, this should be because you didn't insert an SD Card in your phone, so the result of the folder is null, or the SD Card is inserted, but there is no folder called backup. if you're sure you have the folder and the problem still exist, you can post a question describing this specific which different so far from your initial question in this post, which is already solved, this is called a new issue, thanks for your understanding

Comment: When using internal memory with this code : `File folder = new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/DCIM/Camera");` Error gives null array

Comment: try adding the method `getPath()` , I already edited my answer.. if it doesn't work, please post a new question with this issue which different from the initial question, thanks